# "Cannot access network drive"

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share, forbidden

I am experiencing problems when trying to access a network drive. Access is forbidden.
I have added myself as authorized user to this drive with full access, but access is forbidden nevertheless.

Used systems: Windows Server 2003 (to change authorizations), Windows 7 (local computer)

Comment: did this work before and now doesn't?  or is it newly created or changed?

Comment: no, it never worked

Comment: Do you see the list of shares when you look at \\servername ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have NTFS as well as Share permissions to access the drive?

Is the drive being mapped properly? Run NET USE from the command line to see currently mapped drives.

Comment: other things to check assuming you are on domain: Server and Client time are within 5min of each other.

Comment: your access to files over a network share are the combo of both share permissions and NTFS permissions, and the most restrictive wins.  Please update us with your progress.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds for me you would be wiser if you took a look at your ntfs permissions on your network drive.

Being summer and all, I won't try to be too helpful, but this link might help you on the way: http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Understanding-Windows-NTFS-Permissions.html

Good luck!